# Wordpress capability to edit only uploaded files

Tags: php, wordpress, user-roles

I need to assign to an user role the capabilities for the user to only edit his own uploaded files (instead of edit all files like happen for the capability **upload_files**).
Considering that there is not a native capability for that, how can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you could:

1. Define your role and add a custom capability (eg. edit_own_files) via [Roles and Capabilities](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/users/roles-and-capabilities/) guidelines
2. Use the [user_has_cap](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_has_cap/) filter to modify whether the user has the "upload_files" capability - depending on which file they are trying to edit, and if they are the author.

That approach depends on the "upload_files" check passing what you need via the "$args" parameter.

So, you'll have to do some testing - and if it doesn't do what you need, you might need to hunt for a different filter.